# Issue with SurfaceView on 4.1.2 works fine on 4.3

Tags: android, surfaceview, vlc, libvlc

I have a surfaceview in a fragment, that I then use with the android port of VLC to display a video stream, This surface view is only half the size of the screen.

I'm seeing an issue on a note 2 running android 4.1.2 where the video will not show (only a black view) in the surface view until I tell it to go full screen. Odd thing is the surface view works just fine when turn the phone screen off and back on.

On my other note 2 running 4.3 the preview works fine in both the smaller and larger size. Is there any known issues with a surface view on 4.1 that I should account for.